# Verify an identity in probability

Tags: probability

Verify the identity:

$$P(A\cup B)=P(A)+P(B\cap A')$$

I could verify using the Venn diagram. Is there another way?

Comment: What does P(BA') mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** The sets $Α, Α'$ form a *partition* of the sample space $Ω$, since

1. $Α\cap Α' =\emptyset$
2. $Α\cup Α' = Ω$

In other words, every element of $Ω$ is included in exactly one of the sets $Α, Α'$. Perhaps this explains why you can write $$Β=(Β\cap Α)\cup(Β\cap Α')$$ for any set $Β\subseteq Ω$.

Answer (score 0):

For any two events $A$ and $B$,
$$
\Pr(A\cup B)=\Pr(A)+\Pr(B)-\Pr(A\cap B).
$$
We have that
$$
\Pr(A\cup B)=\Pr(A\cup(B\cap A^c))=\Pr(A)+\Pr(B\cap A^c)-\Pr(A\cap(B\cap A^c))=\Pr(A)+\Pr(B\cap A^c)
$$
since $A\cap(B\cap A^c)=\emptyset$ and $\Pr(A\cap(B\cap A^c))=0$.

Answer (score 0):

$P(A\cup B)= P(A) + P(B) - P(A\cap B), P(B) = P(B \cap A) + P(B\cap A')$ and from these equations, the answer follows.

Answer (score 0):

$A\cup B=A\cup(B\cap A^c)$ where $A$ and $B\cap A^c$ are **disjoint**.

So if we are dealing with measurable sets then $$P(A\cup B)=P(A\cup(B\cap A^c))=P(A)+P(B\cap A^c)$$